# Spring boot Hibernate OneToMany Null JoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have entities where one field has an one-to-many relationship.

It looks like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "short_name", nullable = false)
    private String shortName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "customer_number", nullable = false)
    private String customerNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = “company”)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<BusinessType> businessTypes = new HashSet<>();

    … getters setters


}

@Entity
@Table(name = “business_type")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class BusinessType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    private BType type;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private Company company;

    … getters setters
}

public enum BType {
    TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3
}
```

The database tables look like this:

**company(id, name, short_name, customer_number)**

**business_type(id, type, company_id)**

When I request a specific REST path I get the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : “Business name”,
  "shortName" : "Business short name",
  "customerNumber" : "1234",
  “businessTypes" : null
}
```

But I'm expecting the following:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : “Business name”,
  "shortName" : "Business short name",
  "customerNumber" : "1234",
  "businessTypes" : [{
    "id" : 1,
    “type” : “TYPE1”
  }]
}
```

Why is `businessTypes` `null` when the values are in the database?

What am I missing?

Comment: It's lazy fetched. You need to specifically fetch child entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Default is LAZY and relation entity is not loaded unless explicitly requested

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@JoinColumn(name="company_id")` after `@ManyToOne`